# How to Improve Server Response Time in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, performance, .htaccess, pagespeed, w3-total-cache

I was using [W3 Total Cache Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) other then this plugin what I want to do to speeding up my WordPress site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise to, instead of using more plugin use less plugins, ofcourse how fast you can make your website depends on the speed of your server.

First of all check your page via the console(F12) and go to the network tab. You can see all the elements that are loaded in, and you can check how long it takes for them to load in. So if some load elements load too long check them.(For example you can edit some images if they take too long)

What also helps is the following:

- Check all your images, make sure to convert them to .png wich is usually not a large file size and scale them so you    won't have ridiculous large images, or load times
- Check how many visitors you have, if a lot of people are requesting your  pages(aka visiting them) you may want to upgrade your server / hosting so it can handle those users
- Reduce the resources used per page, so make sure all your css is in one file.

If you use too many plugins these all have to be loaded in as well, only use those wich you really need instead of installing 20+ plugins in the hope of making your pages faster. It usually won't work and make your website load even slower.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a CDN, optimise images (there is a plugin called WP-SmushIt), optimise your database (WP-Optimize plugin) and schedule database optimisation (WP-DB Manager plugin), minify and combine (Minit plugin), enable compression, remove any query strings from CSS and JS files (Remove Query Strings From Static Resources plugin), add an expires header to static resources, lazy load images (jQuery Image Lazy Load plugin), control post revisions (Revision Control plugin), and most importantly make sure you choose a good host - shared servers can be very slow.